# Vuetify VBtn unvisible

Tags: vuetify.js

Have anybody some idea why this VBtn in Vuetify isn't visible? Outside of VMenu it's ok, inside, the space is taken and on hover action works properly but button isn't visible no text no border.

```
  <VAppBar app color="primary" dark flat prominent>
    <VToolbarTitle>
      <Logo />
    </VToolbarTitle>
    <VSpacer />
    <div class="my-auto">
      <ThemeToggle />
    </div>
    <VMenu open-on-hover>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <VBtn color="primary" v-bind="props" :text="t('your.account')" />
      </template>
      <VList>
        <VListItem v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <VListItemTitle>
            <RouterLink :to="{ name: item.routeName }">{{ item.title }}</RouterLink>
          </VListItemTitle>
        </VListItem>
      </VList>
    </VMenu>
  </VAppBar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's primary on primary. Set a different color or use a different variant:

```html
 <VBtn color="secondary" variant="elevated" v-bind="props" :text="t('your.account')" />
```